# Problema con mi snippet de Yoast SEO

Tags: plugin, seo, snippets

He revisado la configuaración de Yoast SEO y una y otra vez y todo está bien.
No me aparecen los snippet de ninguna página. Google me busca las palabras de los artículos en vez del snippet. He indexado la web hace 1 mes y medio nose si tendra algo que ver...
Por ejemplo, en uno de mis articulo (https://viajardescubriendo.com/que-ver-en-sedona/) la palabra clave es: "que ver en Sedona" si lo busco de google en modo incognito me aparece en la primera página pero el snippet que sale no es el mismo que yo he creado en Yoast SEO... 
Espero que me podaís ayudar....

[image: Como aparece realmente...]

[image: Como debería aparecer]

Comment: me para exactamente lo mismo con mi pagina. Configure el spinnet asi:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn54a.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn54a.png) pero cuando busco mi pagina en google : https://www.paprikarecetas.online/kenwood-kmix-kmx750rd/ aparece asi:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puWmB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puWmB.png) tuviste alguna respuesta de por que pasa esto?
saludos

Answer (score 0):

Google rastrea tu web y en ocasiones muestra la parte más relevante del artículo en la meta descripción para intentar resolver de la intención de búsqueda de manera rápida.

Y cuando haces click en el resultado crea un texto ancla dinámico  que te lleva hasta ese párrafo.